# Unexpected animated scrollTop behavior inside a div

Tags: jquery, scroll

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tRa7b/).

HTML:

```
<div></div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  margin-top: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
  $("div").append('<span onclick="move(this)">' + i + '</span><br>');

function move(obj) {
  $("div").animate({scrollTop: $(obj).position().top});
}
```

I'm trying to test this ridiculously simple animated scrollTop in a div with jQuery. It should take the clicked number to the top of the div area... but the positioning is simply unpredictable. I won't say it's random because I can spot a pattern, however I can't understand it.

I tried it with `.position().top`, `.offset().top` and even `[0].getBoundingClientRect().top`, the result is the same.

What function, calculation or context to take into account is missing for this sample to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add current scrolltop of div also

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
  $("div").append('<span onclick="move(this)">' + i + '</span><br>');

window.move = function(obj) {
    var top = $(obj).position().top;
       top  = $("div").scrollTop() + top
  $("div").animate({scrollTop: top});
}
```

please find example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vmd2u/4/)